# When is $L^{p}\left(\Omega \right)$ a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

I am asked the following:

Let $\Omega$ be a measure space such that $\exists A,B \subset \Omega$ where

- $A,B$ are measurable sets
- $0 < |A| < \infty$ and $0 <|B|< \infty$
- $|A \cap B| = 0$

Then $L^{p}(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space $\iff$ $p=2$

------- Attempt at solution --------------

Showing that $L^{2}(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space is not difficult. Simply define
$$
(f,g) = \int_{\Omega}f \cdot \overline{g} d\mu
$$
This is well defined via Hölder's inequality, and the inner product properties are straight forward.

Now, I got stuck trying to show that $L^{p}$ is not a Hilbert space for $p \neq 2$. For $p<1$, $L^{p}$ is not a normed space with such a measure, so I guess the result follows from there. For $p>1$, my idea is to show that $L^{p}$ is not isometrically isomorphic to $l^{2}$, where $l^{2}$ is the space of sequences $(x_{n})$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_{n}^{2} < \infty$. I was trying to use the fact that simple functions are dense in $L^p$ for $p>1$, but I'm not making much progress. Any help would be aprecciated.

Comment: See: paralellogram law.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law  Show if $p \ne 2$ then it fails in $L^p(\Omega)$.  Of course to do this you will use the two sets $A,B$ you are given.  You will have to assume also $|A| > 0, |B| > 0$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Oops, my mistake. The sets have positive measure.

Comment: @GEdgar I'll think for a while. Is my argument correct for $0<p<1$? Also, would the fact that $L^{1}$ and $L^{\infty}$ are not reflexive be enough in those cases?

Comment: Your argument for $p<1$.  Well, $L^p[0,1]$ is not a normed space, but what about other measure spaces?  And: $L^1[0,1]$ and $L^\infty[0,1]$ are not reflexive, but what about other measure spaces?